# How to bring the csv data into spacy v2.0 version

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Currently I have the csv data in below format:

[image]

However I want the data to be in spacy (version 2.0) format, where it should be grouped by "data" column in below format:

[image]

I have tried it to group by "data" field using code below:

```
def data_format():
    df = pd.read_csv("Training_data_sample.csv")
    grouped = df.groupby(['data'])
    df_1 = pd.DataFrame(grouped)
    df_1.to_csv("Test_format.csv", encoding="utf-8",index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
df
    data    positions   field
0   data1   (37,41)     fielf_1
1   data1   (4,14)      fielf_2
2   data1   (88,121)    fielf_3
3   data1   (227,267)   fielf_4
4   data2   (37,41)     fielf_1
5   data2   (4,14)      fielf_2
6   data2   (88,121)    fielf_3
7   data2   (227,267)   fielf_4

df['n'] = df.apply(lambda x: (x['positions'], x['field']), axis=1)
df.groupby('data')['n'].apply(list).reset_index()

    data    n
0   data1   [((37,41), fielf_1), ((4,14), fielf_2), ((88,1...
1   data2   [((37,41), fielf_1), ((4,14), fielf_2), ((88,1...

#if you need the result in dictionary format:
df.groupby('data')['n'].apply(list).to_dict()

{'data1': [('(37,41)', 'fielf_1'), ('(4,14)', 'fielf_2'), ('(88,121)', 'fielf_3'), ('(227,267)', 'fielf_4')],
 'data2': [('(37,41)', 'fielf_1'), ('(4,14)', 'fielf_2'), ('(88,121)', 'fielf_3'), ('(227,267)', 'fielf_4')]}
```

Comment: Thanks but it still not giving desired result as it still prints the first column multiple times while what I want is that it should be in one line with all its ("data_1", {"entities": [(37, 41, "field_1"),(4,14, "field_2),(...)]})

Comment: what is the output format you need ? dictionary ? dataframe ?

Comment: I need the data to be organized in such a way that has list of all fields with indexes in one column like [(37,41,"field_1"),(4,14,"field_2"),(88,121,field_3),(227,267,"field_4"),(77,86,"field_4")] and its data field which is data_1 in this case in one column.

Comment: column_1    column_2
data_1         [(37,41,"field_1"),(4,14,"field_2"),(88,121,field_3),(227,267,"field_4"),(77,86,"field_4")]
data_2         [(1,5, "field_1"), (10,15,"field_2")]

Comment: The format is basically :

TRAIN_DATA = [
              ("Walmart is a leading e-commerce company", {"entities": [(0, 7, "ORG")]}),
              ("I reached Chennai yesterday.", {"entities": [(19, 28, "GPE")]}),
              ("I recently ordered a book from Amazon", {"entities": [(24,32, "ORG")]}),
              ("I was driving a BMW", {"entities": [(16,19, "PRODUCT")]}),
              ("I ordered this from ShopClues", {"entities": [(20,29, "ORG")]}),
              ("Fridge can be ordered in Amazon ", {"entities": [(0,6, "PRODUCT")]})

Comment: Link - https://www.machinelearningplus.com/nlp/training-custom-ner-model-in-spacy/

Comment: like this: ```"data_1", {"entities": [(positions, field), (positions, field), (positions, field)]}```

Comment: Yes that is what, i intended to mention.